# Making a list of post tags in string

Tags: search, tags

I am trying to push post tags to the search index of the WPFTS plugin in order to search my posts by tag names. To achieve this, I have to generate a string with all tags. Here is what I tried:

```
add_filter('wpfts_index_post', function($index, $post)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $data = get_the_tags($post->ID);
    $index['post_tag'] = implode(' ', $data);
    return $index;
}, 3, 2);
```

The problem is I see this new search cluster 'post_tag' in the list, but all data there is empty. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `get_the_tags` returns an array of tag names as string? That's a pretty big assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `get_the_tags()` incorrectly.  It **does not** return an array of tag *names*.  It returns an array of tag **objects**.  Each tag object does contain the tag's name (along with other data), but you can't use `implode()` on that result.

I used your original code just adding a step to put the tag object's name into an array.  Then your code picks up with the implode from there.

```
add_filter('wpfts_index_post', function($index, $post)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $data = get_the_tags($post->ID);

    $tag_array = array();
    foreach( $data as $tag_object ) {
        $tag_array[] = $tag_object->name;
    }

    $index['post_tag'] = implode(' ', $tag_array);
    return $index;
}, 3, 2);
```

Always check the documentation for a function to make sure you are getting the expected result (in this case an object instead of an array).  [See `get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like works, but outputs a warning "$tag_array is not defined" should I initialize it by empty array?

Comment: Yes - I should have done that as well.  I updated the answer to reflect initializing an array to get it started.